# Error while obtaining URL/path of app using LSCopyApplicationURLsForBundleIdentifier and CFArrayGetValueAtIndex

Tags: swift, xcode, core-services

I am using `LSCopyApplicationURLsForBundleIdentifier` to get the URL(s) of an installed third-party app on the target system based on its bundle identifier. However, when trying to retrieve the first URL from the returned `CFArray`, I keep getting the following error in the debugger at `CFArrayGetValueAtIndex`:

> Thread 1: EXC_BAD_INSTRUCTION (code=EXC_I386_INVOP, subcode=0x0)

Here is the section of my Swift code:

```
let urls = LSCopyApplicationURLsForBundleIdentifier("com.aa.bb" as CFString, nil)
if (urls != nil) {
     let url = unsafeBitCast(CFArrayGetValueAtIndex(urls as! CFArray, 0), to: CFString.self)
}
urls?.release()
url?.release()
```

How can I extract the URL correctly, preferably as `String`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Too complicated, get the pointee with `takeRetainedValue()` – which handles the memory management properly – and cast it to `[URL]`

```
if let urls = LSCopyApplicationURLsForBundleIdentifier("com.aa.bb" as CFString, nil)?.takeRetainedValue() as? [URL],
   let url = urls.first {
     print(url)
}
```

An `unsafeBitCast` from `(CF)URL` to `(CF)String` is impossible anyway, to get a string path write

```
print(url.path)
```

Comment: Excellent! This solution works alike a charm and is so much cleaner too. Thanks for the help!